# Why is subclass's finalize method, which overrides java.lang.Object's finalize method, called?

Tags: java, overriding, finalize

Here is the code block

```
public class Person {

    int age;
    String name;

    //
    @Override
    public void finalize() throws Throwable{
        System.out.println("Garbage collected --->" + this);
    }
}

class test{

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Person p = new Person();
        System.out.println(p.getClass());

        p = null;
        System.gc();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

System.gc() called finalize() method, but the Object's finalize() should be called, why are the subclass's and the superclass's both called?
Thx for your answer!

I guess when superclass's method and subclass's homonymous method are both called, and the instance is of subclass, the priority of subclass's method is higher than superclass's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the fact the finalization has been [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()), how do you infer the superclass' `finalize` is called? You are true that subclass method overrides superclass method and it actually happens in your case - only subclass' `finalize` is invoked. To invoke superclass' `finalize` you should invoke `super.finalize()` but it wouldn't have any effect anyway since default `java.lang.Object` implementation is empty.